# Extracting trees/vegetation as separate point cloud using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, lidar, las, point-cloud

I have ArcGIS Pro 2.4 with 3D Analyst and Spatial Analyst Extensions. I would like to extract all points from a point cloud (.las) file that match a certain classification to a new, separate point cloud.

what I have tried:
I have ran the "Classify LAS By Height" tool and have assigned a class to points matching a certain height above ground. When I filter the point cloud by this new class (change symbology) I see the results I expect, which is great, but I want to extract/save-out these newly "classified" points to a new point cloud (.las) file.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LAStools, Las2las module exactly. There you can Filter points based on classifications and save it in a separate pointcloud.  Las2las is free to use. Here is a [link](http://lastools.org/) where you can download the whole toolset.

This screenshot is just to show you how GUI of las2las looks like.

[image]